# How can I programmatically verify that a PDF file is first-generation?

Tags: pdf, verification

I'm working on a project that involves the Fannie Mae/Freddie Mac Uniform Appraisal Dataset.  The [specification](http://www.freddiemac.com/sell/secmktg/docs/uadspec.pdf) requires that the embedded appraisal PDF file be first-generation.

I understand conceptually what a first-generation PDF file is (printing of a document directly to PDF, rather than a scanned copy or printed and scanned copy).  However, I've done some research and haven't found anything that specifies the properties of a first-generation PDF that could be verified programmatically.

I found a product that allows one to check if a PDF contains text, images, or both:  [Apose.Pdf.Kit for .NET](http://www.aspose.com/documentation/.net-components/aspose.pdf.kit-for-.net/find-whether-pdf-file-contains-images-or-text-only.html), but I'm looking for a way to program this myself, for budgetary and other reasons.  Also, I'm not sure that determining that the file contains text will be sufficient to verify that it's first-generation.

Given that this is an industry requirement of a very large industry, I feel like someone must have already tackled this issue, but I'm having a hard time finding anything.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: I think you'll get more traction if you boil the question and summary down to your main objective.  You're not trying to determine if a PDF file is "first-generation" but rather if text included in a document is still in text format and not image format.  I'm not even sure if that will work for you if your documents have signatures, which would require them to be scanned at least one (unless embedded signature images are being used).

Comment: @D.N. That's a good point about the signatures.  The appraisal PDF files are generated by software, with the portions having signatures (such as the appraiser license) embedded as an image.  The rest is text forms and photos.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no way to know for certain if a PDF is "first generation". Technically, a scanned PDF is just a PDF that contains images and perhaps OCR'ed text on top of that. A "first generation" PDF could easily have the same characteristics, so you have to use some heuristics.

For example, a PDF that contains only images and invisible text (from OCR) is likely to be scanned, a PDF that has visible text or vector graphics is probably "first generation" (OCR for scanned PDFs works by overlaying invisible text on top of the original image, so that text selection works, but the original document's fidelity is preserved).

Comment: That sounds reasonable. Do you know of any free APIs that allow programmatically checking for visible text?

Comment: By the way, I'm programming in .NET.

Comment: [iText](http://itextpdf.com/) seems to be popular in the .NET/Java world. You'll probably also have to familiarize yourself with the [PDF Spec](http://wwwimages.adobe.com/www.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/devnet/pdf/pdfs/adobe_supplement_iso32000_1.pdf) to make good use of it.

Comment: Thanks for the tips.  I'll check out iText and the PDF spec.

Answer (score 0):

Open pdf, ctrl "f" type in Appraisal.  If you have a hit for the word, you have a first generation apprsl.  Rather, the dataset exist.

Comment: I had asked for a programmatic way, so this wouldn't have worked.